# KnockOut.js text binding client side change not updating viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have two dropdowns upon change will update a label. the label is bound to an observably field in my viewModel using text binding. However, when the label text is changed, the viewModel submitted to the server is not updated. I couldn't find related information from knockout website. Am I missing something?

HTML

```
       <select class="string-match-dropdown">
            <option value="*">contains</option>
            <option value="^">starts with</option>
            <option value="$">ends with</option>
            <option value="=">is exactly</option>
            <option value="@@">has value</option>
        </select>
        <select class="date-money-match-dropdown">
            <option value="eq">=</option>
            <option value="noteq"><></option>
            <option value="gt">></option>
            <option value="gteq">>=</option>
            <option value="lt"><</option>
            <option value="lteq">&lt;=</option>
        </select>
        <label class="match-label" data-bind='html: qualifier'></label>
```

JS

```
$('.date-money-match-dropdown').live('change', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.match-label').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});

$('.string-match-dropdown').live('change', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.match-label').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are missing the code from the question! As a starter how do you update the label with jquery? By the way I don't think that the `text` binding is two way... So please post the relevant portion of your code (a repro in JSFiddle would be even better) otherwise we are just guessing here.

Comment: posted the html databinding and jquery code to update the label

Comment: Why do you need jquery to handle the dropdown change? Why don't you use a pure knockout solution http://jsfiddle.net/qXvLp/?

Comment: Laguna, please see the [knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/)

Comment: @nemesv, thanks! i am using what you have in the fiddler. it's working for me. if you want, you can change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario you don't need to use jquery at all.

Because you already have an observable on your viewmodel `qualifier` you just need to use the [`value` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) on your `select`s and Knockout will do the change handling for you:

```
<select class="string-match-dropdown" data-bind='value: qualifier'>
    <option value="*">contains</option>
    <option value="^">starts with</option>
    <option value="$">ends with</option>
    <option value="=">is exactly</option>
    <option value="@@">has value</option>
</select>
<select class="date-money-match-dropdown" data-bind='value: qualifier'>
    <option value="eq">=</option>
    <option value="noteq"><></option>
    <option value="gt">></option>
    <option value="gteq">>=</option>
    <option value="lt"><</option>
    <option value="lteq">&lt;=</option>
</select>
<label class="match-label" data-bind='html: qualifier'></label>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qXvLp/)